# Intellij formatter chained method calls

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting, auto-indent

How to force IntellJ code formatter to autoindent wrapped arguments list on different level than wrapped chained method calls:

**EDIT:** See updated examples for better problem description. The default formatter works as expected if I wrap each consecutive method call to a new line. The problem occurs only if I want to leave one or more dots per line:

Wrapping this:

```
new Something()
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", "very long arg I want to see in new line");
```

I would expect something like this:

```
new Something()
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line");
```

But the result is:

```
new Something()
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .chained("arg1", "arg2", 
        "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", 
    "very long arg I want to see in new line")
    .extra().chained("arg1", "arg2", 
    "very long arg I want to see in new line");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces

Configure **Chained method calls** to **Wrap always** and mark **Align when multiline**:

[image]